# Wrong permissions sets sticky bit

Tags: php, linux, directory, file-permissions

A few days ago, I happened to set the permissions wrongly when using the php-function `mkdir` like this:

```
mkdir("foldername", 777, true);
```

The correct way is, asuming you want those kind of permissions:

```
mkdir("foldername", 0777, true);
```

I know that I shouldn't use 777 on my files or folders but this is for a very closed system, so please don't get stuck on that. Because here comes the funny(weird) part, at least, for me. Because we noted that something was very strange when this script created folders. The persmissions that gets set is really strange, especially for a non-power-user of linux like me. Because what we see is that the permissions of the created folders gets set to this:

> d r - - - - x - - t

Which to me is strange, I hadn't heard about the sticky bit before (the `t`) but that is apparently set when you want to make that file only removable by root. Does anyone know why PHP behaves like this, or if it even is a PHP issue (not really an issue, since I'm then one using the function wrongly), or is this something that our *nix system does by default when in doubt or something?

Comment: Usually `mkdir("foldername", 01777, true);` sets the sticky bit. Not sure why just 777 would set it.

Comment: The file permissions are in octal notation (base 8). 777 is decimal there and it means 01411 octal which sets the sticky one too...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file permissions are in octal notation (base 8).

777 is decimal there and it means 01411 octal which sets the sticky one too...

Answer (score 1):

Someone answered this question and then deleted it, which is sad, because I strongly think it was correct. So if you read this, please post that answer again, and I'll accept it.

Anyways it seems that php translates the `decimal 777` to `octal 1411` and that will set the permissions to what I got, namely:

> d r - - - - x - - t